How to calculate the reference level interaction in regression in R?
I am very confused on calculating the reference level interaction in regression in R.
Here is the sample code:
library(magrittr)
set.seed(123)
x = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1)
x %<>% as.factor()
z=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3)
z %<>% as.factor()

y = runif(8)

lm(y~x*x1)
lm(y~x:x1)
lm(y~x+x1)

The result is as below:
> lm(y ~ x*z)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x * z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x2          z2          z3       x2:z2       x2:z3  
    0.18883      0.09349      0.07071      0.17709     -0.21342      0.08697  

> lm(y ~ x:x1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x:z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       x1:z1       x2:z1       x1:z2       x2:z2       x1:z3       x2:z3  
     0.5464      -0.3576      -0.2641      -0.2868      -0.4068      -0.1805           NA  

> lm(y ~ x+z)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x2          z2          z3  
    0.19377      0.08362     -0.03600      0.22057  

How to calculate the reference level interaction term x1:z1 from lm(y~x*z)?
e.g. $x1:z2 = z2 - x2:z2 = 0.07071 - (-0.21342)$?
Also, why didn't r estimate the coefficients of x1:z2 and x1:z3 as same as the regression in lm(y~x:z)? Is it related to collinearity?

The "reference level" of the model with * is given by the intercept. Btw, you could make your and our life so much easier by calling the second covariate z.

Does it mean that $intercept = x1  +x1:z1$?

I 'd say so, but better try it out by using a model x * z + 0 (to set the intercept to 0).

Understanding Reference Levels and Interaction Terms
When using  treatment contrasts (the default in R), each coefficient in the model represents the difference between a given level of the factor and the reference level. In practical terms, treatment contrasts assign the first factor level as the baseline, and the coefficients for the other levels indicate how much the outcome differs from this baseline. This is important when interpreting main effects and interactions, as all comparisons are relative to this reference level.
For example, if a factor has levels $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$, with $A_1$ as the reference, the estimated coefficients for $A_2$ and $A_3$ will indicate how the dependent variable differs when $A_2$ or $A_3$ is present, compared to $A_1$. That is, the estimates are contrasts with the reference level.
Similarly, when interaction terms are included, the reference interaction (eg. $A_1:B_1$) is absorbed into the intercept. The model estimates interaction terms for all other combinations of the factor levels (relative to the baseline interaction). Consequently, the interpretation of these interaction terms is always relative to the reference-level combination of both factors, and missing interaction terms (such as for the reference levels) are implied within the intercept to prevent perfect multicollinearity.
Also note that when a variable is interacted with another, the main effects are conditional on the other variable being held at it's reference level (in the case of continuous variables, then it is conditional on the other variable being held at zero).
In your case:

Factor x has two levels: x1 (reference) and x2.
Factor z has three levels: z1 (reference), z2, and z3.

When you fit a model with interactions (eg, y ~ x * z), the interaction terms include both the main effects (for x and z) and the interactions (x:z). The reference interaction (in your case, x1:z1) is incorporated into the intercept, which is the baseline for the combination of the reference levels of both factors.
Understanding the Model lm(y ~ x * z)
The model lm(y ~ x * z) includes both the main effects and the interaction terms for x and z. It can be expanded as:
$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x_2 + \beta_2 \cdot z_2 + \beta_3 \cdot z_3 + \beta_4 \cdot (x_2 \cdot z_2) + \beta_5 \cdot (x_2 \cdot z_3) + \epsilon
$$
Where:

$\beta_0$ is the intercept, representing the fitted value when both $x_1$ and $z_1$ (the reference levels) are observed.
$\beta_1$ represents the effect of $x_2$ relative to $x_1$.
$\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ represent the effects of $z_2$ and $z_3$ relative to $z_1$.
$\beta_4$ and $\beta_5$ represent the interaction effects between $x_2$ and $z_2$, and $x_2$ and $z_3$, respectively, compared to the baseline interaction $x_1:z_1$, which is absorbed into the intercept.

2. Interaction Terms and Reference Levels

The interaction term for $x_1:z_1$ is absorbed into the intercept because $x_1$ and $z_1$ are the reference levels.

The interaction term for $x_1:z_2$ can be calculated by subtracting the interaction term for $x_2:z_2$ from the main effect of $z_2$:
$$
x_1:z_2 = \beta_2 - \beta_4 = 0.07071 - (-0.21342) = 0.28413
$$

Similarly, for $x_1:z_3$:
$$
x_1:z_3 = \beta_3 - \beta_5 = 0.17709 - 0.08697 = 0.09012
$$


Why Some Interaction Terms Are "Missing"
R doesn't estimate the interaction for x_1:z_1 because including all levels would lead to perfect multicollinearity. In regression, perfect multicollinearity occurs when one predictor can be exactly predicted from others, causing redundancy. For instance, if all interaction terms were included, the model could perfectly predict the intercept, which would create dependency between the predictors. To avoid this, reference-level interactions are absorbed into the intercept to ensure a unique and stable solution for the model.
Differences in Other Models

lm(y ~ x + z): This model assumes no interaction between x and z. The main effects of x and z are estimated independently.
lm(y ~ x:z): This model includes only interaction terms but not the main effects. Missing terms in the out (such as NA for x2:z3) occur because the model does not include main effects, and R cannot estimate certain coefficients.

Summary
Intercept (0.18883): Baseline value when x=1 and z=1.
Calculation: $\hat{y} = \beta_0 = 0.18883$
x2 (0.09349): Effect of x=2 relative to x=1 when z=1.
Calculation: $\hat{y}(x=2, z=1) - \hat{y}(x=1, z=1) = \beta_1 = 0.09349$
z2 (0.07071): Effect of z=2 relative to z=1 when x=1.
Calculation: $\hat{y}(x=1, z=2) - \hat{y}(x=1, z=1) = \beta_2 = 0.07071$
z3 (0.17709): Effect of z=3 relative to z=1 when x=1.
Calculation: $\hat{y}(x=1, z=3) - \hat{y}(x=1, z=1) = \beta_3 = 0.17709$
x2:z2
(-0.21342): Interaction effect of x=2 and z=2 (combined effect is 0.21342 units lower than the sum of individual effects).
Calculation: $\hat{y}(x=2, z=2) - [\hat{y}(x=1, z=1) + \beta_1 + \beta_2] = \beta_4 = -0.21342$
x2:z3
(0.08697): Interaction effect of x=2 and z=3 (combined effect is 0.08697 units higher than the sum of individual effects).
Calculation: $\hat{y}(x=2, z=3) - [\hat{y}(x=1, z=1) + \beta_1 + \beta_3] = \beta_5 = 0.08697$
Conclusion
In regression models with interactions, reference-level combinations (such as $x_1:z_1$) are embedded in the intercept, and interaction terms for reference levels are not explicitly shown due to collinearity concerns. The interaction terms modify the main effects, showing how the relationship between two variables changes across their levels. You can manually calculate any "missing" interaction terms by subtracting interaction effects from the main effects of non-reference levels, as these interactions are relative to the baseline interaction absorbed in the intercept.

In regression analysis, the reference level of a factor variable is the level that is not included as one of the dichotomous variables that are created from that factor variable.
Let's take your first model lm(formula = y ~ x * z). Based on the regression output, we see that the reference level of x is x=1 and the reference of z is z=1. Therefore, for the reference observation (which has x=z=1), x2, z2, z3, x2:z2, x2:z3 are all zero.
If you now plug in into the formula you will see that you are left with only the intercept.
And yes, we cannot include the full set of interactions because of perfect multicolinearity.

You mean I can't calculate x1,x1:z1 from the equation y~x*z?

If you have an observation that has x=1 and z=1 (and therefore x1:z1=1) then the fitted value of y for this observation will be the intercept. This is because inserting into the estimated model yields  0.18883 + 00.09349  + 00.07071+ 00.17709 + 0-0.21342 + 0*0.08697= 0.18883 = Intercept. Does that make sense to you?

How about x1 itself? Intercept should equal to x1+x1:z1?

You cannot compute a fitted value for an observation where you only know the value of one variable. The regression coefficient of x2 0.09349 tells us that the fitted value of an observation with x=2 will be 0.09349 units higher than for an observation with x=1. The exact value of y for a given observation of course depends on the values of all other variables.
